# What is "length" of a string in Bourne shell compatibles' `${#string}`?

Tags: bash, zsh, unicode, bourne-shell, byte

Arising from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685602/count-bytes-of-filename/685603?noredirect=1#comment1295723_685603) discussion:

When I have (zsh 5.8, bash 5.1.0)

```bsh
var="ASCII"
echo "${var} has the length ${#var}, and is $(printf "%s" "$var"| wc -c) bytes long"
```

the answer is simple: these are 5 characters, occupying five bytes.

Now, `var=Müller` yields

```
Müller has the length 6, and is 7 bytes long
```

Which suggests the `${#}` operator counts codepoints, not bytes. This is a bit unclear [in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), where they say it counts "characters". This would be clearer if `char`acters in POSIX C weren't octets, normally.

Anyways: Nice! Kind of good, seeing that `LANG==en_US.utf8`.

Now,

```bsh
var='‍♀️'
echo "${var} has the length ${#var}, and is $(printf "%s" "$var"| wc -c) bytes long"
```

```
‍♀️ has the length 5, and is 17 bytes long
```

Soooo, we decompose "Mermaid of dark skin color" into the Unicode codepoint

1. Merperson
2. Dark skin tone
3. Zero-Width Joiner
4. Female
5. Print print the previous character as emoji

Fine, so we're really counting Unicode codepoints!

```bsh
var="e\xcc\x81"
echo "${var} has the length ${#var}, and is $(printf "%s" "$var"| wc -c) bytes long"
```

```
é has the length 9, and is 9 bytes long
```

(of course, my console font decided that the `´` combines with the following space, not the preceding `e`. The latter would be correct. But let's leave my rage about that for somewhen else.)

Um, a slight "wat" is in order here.

```bsh
> printf "e\xcc\x81"|wc -c
3
> printf "%s" "${var}" |wc -c
9
> echo -n ${var} |wc -c
3
> echo "${var} has the length ${#var}, and is $(printf "%s" "$var"| wc -c) bytes long"
é has the length 9, and is 9 bytes long
> printf "%s" "${var}" |xxd
00000000: 655c 7863 635c 7838 31                   e\xcc\x81
```

Here's where I give up.

`echo $var`, `echo ${var}` and `echo "${var}"` all "correctly" emit three bytes. However, `echo ${#var}` tells me it's 9 charachters.

Where is this documented/standardized, what's the rules for all this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In POSIX compliant shells (not the Bourne shell, that feature comes from the Korn shell), `${#var}` like `wc -m` counts the number of [characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_87)¹ in `$var` and the behaviour is unspecified if the sequence of bytes stored in `$var` cannot be decoded to characters in the current locale.

Bytes are decoded into characters as per the current locale (its `LC_CTYPE` category). In a locale that uses UTF-8 as the character encoding, the 0xc3 0xa9 sequence would be decoded into a `é` character, while in a locale using ISO8859-1, that would be decoded into `Ã©` and in a locale using BIG5 into `矇`.

In any case, it has little to do with Unicode codepoints. It's also not the same as counting the number of grapheme clusters or the width of the string when displayed by a terminal or any other display device.

In:

```
var="e\xcc\x81"
```

`$var` contains 9 bytes and 9 characters: `e`, `\`, `x`, `c`, `c`, `\`, `x`, `8` and `1`.

Some `printf` (in the format argument or in arguments for `%b` format directives) and `echo` implementations will expand `\xcc` to the 0xcc byte, not all do. Per POSIX, `\x` in an argument to those leads to unspecified behaviour. (`\351` does expand to the 0xe9 byte in `printf` format argument and `\0351` in `echo`/`%b` though).

If you want `$var` to contain the `0x65`, `0xcc`, `0x81` bytes, in `ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash` (and these days more and more shells), you'd do:

```
var=$'e\xcc\x81'
```

Or you could always do:

```
var=$(printf 'e\314\201')
```

Then in a locale where `locale charmap` outputs `UTF-8`, `$var` would contain 3 bytes (as shown by `wc -c`), 2 characters (as shown by `wc -m` or `${#var}`), 1 grapheme cluster (as shown by GNU `grep -Po '\X'`) usually displayed with width 1 (as shown by GNU `wc -L`).

If the locale at the time the shell was invoked and at the time the code was parsed and executed had UTF-8 as the charset, in several shells, you can also do:

```
var=$'e\u0301'
```

For `$var` to contain the UTF-8 encoding of the `e` and U+0301 (combining acute accent) characters.

If the locale's charset is not UTF-8, then the behaviour varies between shells. Also whether it's the locale that was in effect at the time the code was parsed or at the time the code was executed that is taken into account to expand the Unicode codepoint into a character depends on the shell. You'll find also variations of behaviour if the character is not present in the locale's charmap.

In the Bourne shell, to get the length in characters of a string, you had to resort to other utilities such as:

```
length=`expr "x$var" : '.*' - 1` || :
```

Or:

```
length=`printf %s "$var" | wc -m`
```

Though if you find a system old enough to still have a Bourne shell, chances are that its `wc` won't support `-m` or that there won't be a `printf` command.

---

<sup>¹ POSIX itself doesn't specify the mapping between sequences of bytes and characters, not even in the POSIX locale, only some APIs to define and retrieve that mapping or convert sequences of bytes to sequence of characters (`wchar_t`). Systems generally use standard charsets for the charmap like UTF-8 which is a transformation format of the charset defined by another ISO standard (ISO/IEC 10646 aka Unicode). Some systems like GNU ones actually use the Unicode code points for the `wchar_t` values regardless of the locale.</sup>

Comment: nice!  `locale charmap` tells me `UTF-8`, and `var=$'e\xcc\x81'; echo ${#var}` tells me 2.

Comment: This might be slightly going off on a tangent, but what exactly *is* a character, then?

Comment: @MarcusMüller see [the POSIX definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_87) for instance.

Comment: but.. but that would mean `è` is a single character,  no matter how it was composed: *A sequence of one or more bytes representing a **single graphic symbol** or control code.*

Comment: @MarcusMüller Two levels of abstraction, I think. From the POSIX perspective, both `e` and the composing grave accent would be considered two printable characters. It's the display device that would be responsible for *rendering* them as the single character `è`.